# Web Service running locally won't connect to local database

Tags: sql-server, web-services, iis, connection

I have a web service that's running locally via IIS. Using IE to navigate to it to test a specific service instantly returns 0 (default value returned by the stored procedure that gets called when something invalid is entered). However, if I change the connection string in `web.config` to connect to the server where the live database is hosted it works just fine. If I change the connection string to an invalid name for the server and try to test the service, it will load for about 15 seconds before returning 0, so I'm fairly certain the whole connection string is correct. I'm thinking it's something permission related with either SQL, IIS or both.

My connection string is:

```
<add name="LocalSQLServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL_R2;Initial Catalog=localDBcopy;Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I connect it to the live server I replace `Trusted_Connection` with a name and password.

Why can't I connect to my local database? Or if I am connecting, why can't I run a stored procedure that's called through the web service? Any thoughts, or need any additional info?

Comment: are you sure you have a **My** SQL server? Looks like the connection string for a **MS** SQL server

Comment: Oops, yea it's MS SQL. Not sure how I managed to put the wrong tag. Unfortunately I don't have the rep to retag it.

Comment: I'd suspect that somewhere in your code base you have a `catch(Exception ex){}` block that's swallowing error messages and making it next to impossible to diagnose. Find it and permanently delete it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't think that's the case. Every `catch` either returns -1 or a message. There are no empty catches.

Comment: The issue is, you suspect that errors are happening, but you've not been able to give us any error messages. If errors are, indeed, occurring, then *something* is hiding that information from you (and, in turn, us). I just listed the number one suspect. Without knowing *what* errors are happening, it's a tad tricky to diagnose.

Comment: So the project for the web service didn't have a solution file, so I whipped one up and dropped the files in so I could run it through VS and try to debug to get some errors...and it works just fine. I'll see if this will suit my needs for the time being.